# URL Tracking URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, ups

We are programming a website which use UPS as shipping method. Administrator of the site must approve every order manually, create things propertly with UPS and then just get the tracking number and put it in our system. So we do not use any API from UPS or anything.

Is there a "static" URL like : http://ups.com/apage/{0} we may format to replace the {0} by the tracking number that the administrator will enter in our system?

I know I could search in google, but I'm not realy sure of what to write after UPS URL Tracking number didn't results me anything usefull.

Comment: I'm suprised UPS don't have an api.

Comment: UPS has an API and this sort of misusing the manual tracking facilities is against their Terms...

Comment: @Yagua : Thank to advertise us.

Comment: @Oliver : I don't say they don't have API, I'm telling we do not use their API.

Comment: Is there a reason you cant use the API to generate the tracking url?  This approach will generally be safer as if UPS change their URL your site breaks, whereas any changes to the API will generally be done safely so existing code isnt broken

Comment: As I just dunno how the real way to do it, I though this may be an easier way to do it because the client don't want to pay a lot for this. Also, I were dunno if using the API mean we must go through the whole process of asking for placing an shipping request, retreive informations and everything. So if API allows us to do this, I'll use the API then ...

Comment: You're not using their API because you don't know how to use it?  But you don't know how to do this, either....

Comment: Thats exactly why I asked my question ; if it's possible to do this with the easiest way I expected : URL. After what, if it's impossible, API surely be an option. But as Yahia said and what I dunno, it's against their terms. So, yes, I'll use the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are required to use the [UPS API](https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit) when interacting with their system to either track packages or manage shipments. Any other use is in violation of their terms of service.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know their terms of service as others have mentioned, but GMail just links to the following when it finds a tracking number in a message. I would assume you could use the same:

http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/processInputRequest?TypeOfInquiryNumber=T&InquiryNumber1=TRACKINGNUMBER

I'm sure this could end up changing at some point down the road.

Comment: Thanks. I've forget to mention it in my main question, but I'm french and something have hard time searching web for answer, thats why I write it here when I don't find. I though I may be not the only one who may want to know that. Thanks Doozer.

Comment: As I said, I don't claim to know the Terms of Service, and others could be right. They may not allow direct linking like this without some sort of agreement. You would likely be better off with their API if this is to change down the road and it would ensure that it won't break any rules.

Comment: Yeah thank you. I'll use the API in order to follow the fact that the URL may change plus, ensure to not break any rules too.